# How to keep incrementing the same value?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

```
Try
    Dim count as Int64
    Using cm As New SQLiteCommand("SELECT COUNT([RollNo]) FROM [StudentTbl]", cn)
        If Not cm.ExecuteScalar() Is DBNull.Value Then
            count = Convert.ToInt64(cm.ExecuteScalar())
        Else
            count = 0
        End If
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox(ex.Message)
     Return
End Try
txtRollNo.Text = count +1
```

Comment: That `ExecuteNonQuery` call can never return `DBNull.Value` because the SQL `COUNT` function can never return `NULL`.  It ALWAYS returns a number.  If there are no matches then it returns zero.  Just call `ExecuteScalar` once, cast as type `Long` and assign to `count`.

Comment: Hello @Jimi  I don't understand please. Make it more simple. Thanks

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move the count declaration outside the Try block otherwise it will not be visible outside the block. You attempt to use it outside the block.
2. You cannot assign a number to a .Text property. It requires a String. Convert count + 1 to a String.
3. Keep your database objects local so you can control that they are closed and disposed. This is particulary important for connections which are precious resources.
4. Why are you executing your query twice?
5. In most SQL languages Count will not return null. It will return 0 if there are no rows the match criteria.
6. It pains me to think that you have a Class level variable that is an Open connection. Get rid of it if you do. In my code you must open the connection before executing the command.
7. Good job converting the return value of the `ExecuteScalar`. Also good job passing the command text and the connection to the constructor of the command.
8. I am a bit leery of why you want this number. If you are expecting to use count +1 for the next primary key -- DON'T. If this is a multi-user environment then it will not work. Even if it is single user, suppose you have deleted a few records. Your method will give you a duplicate Primary Key. Set your `RollNo` field to auto-increment/identity and the database will do it for you.

```vb
Private Sub GetCount()
    Dim count As Int64
    Try
        Using cn As New SQLiteConnection("Your connection string")
            Using cm As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand("SELECT COUNT([RollNo]) FROM [StudentTbl]", cn)
                cn.Open()
                count = Convert.ToInt64(cm.ExecuteScalar())
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
    txtRollNo.Text = CStr(count + 1)
End Sub
```